Visual Studio Code Makefile extension not executing make as expected
Executing make command on this Makefile compiles as expected:
#SHELL = /bin/sh

APP:= basic-tutorial-2
APP_INSTALL_DIR?= $(HOME)/Projects/test-gstreamer-2/build/bin

CC:=/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc

SRCS:= $(wildcard *.c)
INCS:= $(wildcard *.h)
PKGS:= gstreamer-1.0
OBJS:= $(SRCS:.c=.o)

CFLAGS:= $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(PKGS))
LIBS:= $(shell pkg-config --libs $(PKGS))

#$(info $$CFLAGS is [${CFLAGS}]) <-- Print variable

all: $(APP)

%.o: %.c $(INCS) 
    $(CC) -ggdb -O0 -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<

$(APP): $(OBJS) 
    $(CC) -ggdb -O0 -o $(APP) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

install: $(APP)
    cp -rv $(APP) $(APP_INSTALL_DIR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(APP)
    rm $(APP_INSTALL_DIR)/$(APP)

steven@development-orin:~/Projects/test-gstreamer-2/build$ ls -al
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steven steven 2291 Apr  3 17:15 basic-tutorial-2.c
drwxrwxr-x 2 steven steven 4096 Apr  4 16:07 bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steven steven  613 Apr  3 19:17 Makefile
steven@development-orin:~/Projects/test-gstreamer-2/build$ make
/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -ggdb -O0 -c -o basic-tutorial-2.o -pthread -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -I/usr/i                                       nclude/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include basic-tutorial-2.c
/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -ggdb -O0 -o basic-tutorial-2 basic-tutorial-2.o -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0

steven@development-orin:~/Projects/test-gstreamer-2/build$ ls -al
-rwxrwxr-x 1 steven steven 21992 Apr  4 16:21 basic-tutorial-2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steven steven  2291 Apr  3 17:15 basic-tutorial-2.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steven steven 19992 Apr  4 16:21 basic-tutorial-2.o
drwxrwxr-x 2 steven steven  4096 Apr  4 16:07 bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steven steven   613 Apr  3 19:17 Makefile

Application basic-tutorial-2 is created as expected.
However, when I attempt to compile in Visual studio code:


I get this
 *  Executing task: '/usr/bin/make' '-f' '/home/steven/Projects/test-gstreamer-2/build/Makefile' 

/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -ggdb -O0 -o basic-tutorial-2  -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `main'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/home/steven/Projects/test-gstreamer-2/build/Makefile:24: basic-tutorial-2] Error 1

 *  The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', ''/usr/bin/make' '-f' '/home/steven/Projects/test-gstreamer-2/build/Makefile''" failed to launch (exit code: 2). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

I'm hoping the answer is NOT to change the Makefile, but to configure VSC differently. Any ideas?
#1 Source file contents:
// basic-tutorial-2.c
#include <gst/gst.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GstElement *pipeline, *source, *sink;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  GstStateChangeReturn ret;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Create the elements */
  source = gst_element_factory_make ("videotestsrc", "source");
  sink = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "sink");

  /* Create the empty pipeline */
  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");

  if (!pipeline || !source || !sink) {
    g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  /* Build the pipeline */
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, sink, NULL);
  if (gst_element_link (source, sink) != TRUE) {
    g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
    return -1;
  }

  /* Modify the source's properties */
  g_object_set (source, "pattern", 0, NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  ret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
    return -1;
  }

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  msg =
      gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
      GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Parse message */
  if (msg != NULL) {
    GError *err;
    gchar *debug_info;

    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
      case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
        gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
        g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n",
            GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
        g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n",
            debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
        g_clear_error (&err);
        g_free (debug_info);
        break;
      case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
        g_print ("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
        break;
      default:
        /* We should not reach here because we only asked for ERRORs and EOS */
        g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
        break;
    }
    gst_message_unref (msg);
  }

  /* Free resources */
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
}

#2 When I run make from command line
$(info $$SRCS is [${SRCS}]) ---> $SRCS is [basic-tutorial-2.c]
$(info $$OBJS is [${OBJS}]) ---> $OBJS is [basic-tutorial-2.o]

When I run from Visual Studio Code
$(info $$SRCS is [${SRCS}]) ---> $SRCS is []
$(info $$OBJS is [${OBJS}]) ---> $OBJS is []


What are the contents of your source file?

Can you echo ${SRCS} ?

See this response from another question.
SRCS:= $(wildcard *.c) $(wildcard **/*.c)
INCS:= $(wildcard *.h) $(wildcard **/*.h)


It seems that your link command has no objects:
# look carefully how there are 2 spaces here ---------------++
/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -ggdb -O0 -o basic-tutorial-2  -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0

This means that either OBJS or SRCS (or both) are empty.
The linker is (correctly) complaining it has no entry point main.

I moved the basic-tutorial.c from the build directory into the project/root directory and compiled successfully with Visual Studio Code Makefile tools. Seems it doesn't see the file when its not in the project directory. There must be a config to tell VSC to look in a subdirectory for the code?

@Steven yes, there must be. Until you find it, you can try to see what is the working directory of VSC (with pwd)

It's not that you need to "tell VSC to look in a subdirectory for the code".  Visual Code is not "looking for the code".  make is looking for the code (that's what the $(wildcard *.c) does).  The problem is that you are expecting the current directory when make is invoked to be one thing (the build subdirectory), but Visual Code is invoking make with a different working directory.  Add $(info cwd = $(shell pwd)) to your makefile and see the difference when you run it vs. when visual code runs it.
